# Insert data into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making an application in codeigniter using php.I want to insert data into database table where the data is entered in an input box inside a loop.I have tried the below code so far:

**cms_model.php**

```
public function loadadd($mekhala_Id){
    
        $query = $this->db->get_where('tb_unit', array('mandalam_Id' => $mekhala_Id));
        echo  form_open('Payment/amount'); 
    ?>


<h1>Members List</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                 <th>Unit</th>
                  <th>Unit Secretary</th>
                 <th>Amount paid</th>
                 
            </tr>
            <?php
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        ?>

            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row->unitName ;?></td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row->unit_sec ;?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'na','placeholder'=>'Rupees Paid')) ;?></td>  
            </tr>
            <?php
       
}

 echo form_submit(array('name'=>'sub','value'=>'submit'));
        echo form_close();
}



 public function loadpayment($paid){
 
   //  $paid= $this->input->post('na');

           $fieldsData = $this->db->field_data('tb_unit');
           $datacc = array(); // you were setting this to a string to start with, which is bad

     foreach ($fieldsData as $key => $field)
{
    $datacc[ $field->Amount] = $this->input->post( $field->Amount);
}
$this->db->insert('tb_unit', $datacc);

}
   //  $this->db->set('Amount', $paid)



  
}



        
?>
```

I have encountered below error while running this code:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Amount
>
> Filename: models/cms_model.php
>
> Line Number: 110

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Any one please help me to find answer.

Answer (score 0):

change line #110 to:

```
$datacc[$field->name] = $this->input->post($field->name);
```

Comment: Still data is not being inserted into the database table

Comment: can you tell the error after changing your editing your code?

Comment: No error..But data is not being inserted into the database table.

Comment: can you tell me what you are trying to achieve??

Comment: Actually i want to store the data that is inserted into the the input box which is provided inside a loop..While running the above code no error is being shown where as the inserted data is not stored in the database table.How can i resolve this problem???

Comment: as i can see you are trying to write data to the same table you are reading from do you want to update that data or just to insert a new row??

Comment: I just  want to insert data into new row that is being created in the same table

Comment: can you share your able schema?

Comment: Sorry..I din get you

Comment: The column names are as follows:unit_Id,DistrictId,mandalam_Id,unitName,unit_sec,Amount

Comment: last question, is there any way your query is going to return more than one row?

Comment: Yes,Data inserted in Multiple input boxes should be stored in database table

Comment: how do you call `loadpayment` method ??

Comment: public function amount()
 {
         
            //$mekhala_Id=   $this->input->post('mekhala');
        //$query = $this->db->get_where('tb_unit', array('mandalam_Id' => $mekhala_Id));
        //$count= $query->num_rows();
         $paid=array($this->input->post('na'));
       // $query= $this->db->get('tb_unit');
        
         $this->cms_model->loadpayment($paid);
            }

Comment: when a button is clicked,amount() method is called..Inside this method loadpayment() method is being called

Comment: Can any one help me to find solution to my problem.Please